# Color System Computer graphic

Tags: graphics

Suppose that when you power on a computer its monitor displays predominantly variations of black and magenta. You suspect that one of the three wires RGB in your monitor cable is no longer properly connected. Which one is it? Show your reasoning?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question.

Comment: Are we talking about the pinout of the RGB VGA standard cable? If so then look at the following: http://www.geocities.ws/podernixie/htpc/cables-en.html

Comment: Computer graphics are not programming !!!! Hehehehe I do not care that you use the paint program in painting and no have time to clear you what is the computer graphics

Comment: Magenta is Blue+Red if you have no other colors then Green is missing and Blue/Red are short-circuit-ed (problem can be elsewhere then just cable) but this has nothing to do with programing nor graphics so +Close